# What is the expected value of the logarithm of Gamma distribution?

Tags: expected-value, gamma-distribution

If the expected value of $\mathsf{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$ is $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$, what is the expected value of $\log(\mathsf{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta))$? Can it be calculated analytically?

The parametrisation I am using is shape-rate.

Comment: If $X \sim \text{Gamma}(a,b)$, then according to mathStatica/Mathematica, $E[ \log(X) ]  = \log(b) $ + PolyGamma[a], where PolyGamma denotes the digamma function

Comment: I should add that you do not provide the pdf form of your Gamma variable, and since you report that the mean is $\alpha/\beta$ (whereas for me it would be $a b$, it appears you are using different notation than I am, where your $\beta= 1/b$

Comment: True, sorry. The parametrisation I am using is shape-rate.

${\displaystyle {\frac {\beta ^{\alpha }}{\Gamma (\alpha )}}x^{\alpha -1}e^{-\beta x}}$

I will try to find it for this parametrisation. Could you please suggest the query for Mathematica/WolframAlpha?

Comment: See also Johnson, Lotz and Balakrishna (1994) continuous univariate distributions Vol 1 2nd Ed. pp. 337-349.

Comment: Also see Wikipedia: [Gamma Distribution # Logarithmic expectation and variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Logarithmic_expectation_and_variance)

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312803, the beginning of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This one (maybe surprisingly) can be done with easy elementary operations (employing Richard Feynman's favorite trick of differentiating under the integral sign with respect to a parameter).

---

We are supposing $X$ has a $\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution and we wish to find the expectation of $Y=\log(X).$  First, because $\beta$ is a scale parameter, its effect will be to *shift* the logarithm by $\log\beta.$  (If you use $\beta$ as a *rate* parameter, as in the question, it will shift the logarithm by $-\log\beta.$) This permits us to work with the case $\beta=1.$

After this simplification, the [probability element](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14490/919) of $X$ is

$$f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^\alpha e^{-x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}$$

where $\Gamma(\alpha)$ is the normalizing constant

$$\Gamma(\alpha) = \int_0^\infty x^\alpha e^{-x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}.$$

Substituting $x=e^y,$ which entails $\mathrm{d}x/x = \mathrm{d}y,$ gives the probability element of $Y$,

$$f_Y(y)\,\mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)} e^{\alpha y - e^y} \mathrm{d}y.$$

The possible values of $Y$ now range over all the real numbers $\mathbb{R}.$

Because $f_Y\,\mathrm{d}y$ must integrate to unity, we obtain (trivially)

$$\Gamma(\alpha) = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{\alpha y - e^y} \mathrm{d}y.\tag{1}$$

Notice $f_Y(y)$ is a differentiable function of $\alpha.$ An easy calculation gives

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}e^{\alpha y - e^y} \mathrm{d}y =  y\, e^{\alpha y - e^y} \mathrm{d}y = \Gamma(\alpha) y\,f_Y(y)\,\mathrm{d}y.$$

The next step exploits the relation obtained by dividing both sides of this identity by $\Gamma(\alpha),$ thereby exposing the very object we need to integrate to find the expectation; namely, $y f_Y(y)\,\mathrm{d}y:$

$$\eqalign{
\mathbb{E}(Y) &= \int_\mathbb{R} y\, f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}e^{\alpha y - e^y} \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\int_\mathbb{R} e^{\alpha y - e^y} \mathrm{d}y\\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)\\
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\log\Gamma(\alpha)\\
&=\psi(\alpha),
}$$

the logarithmic derivative of the gamma function (aka "[polygamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function)").  The integral was computed using identity $(1).$

Re-introducing the factor $\beta$ shows the general result is

$$\mathbb{E}(\log(X)) = \log\beta + \psi(\alpha)$$

for a scale parameterization (where the density function depends on $x/\beta$) or

$$\mathbb{E}(\log(X)) = -\log\beta + \psi(\alpha)$$

for a rate parameterization (where the density function depends on $x\beta$).

Comment: With polygamma function do you mean of which order (e.g., 0,1) being a digamma (As @wolfies pointed out), trigamma?

Comment: @Stefano I mean the logarithmic derivative of gamma, as stated.  That means $\psi(z) = \Gamma^\prime(z)/\Gamma(z).$

Comment: @whuber: Thanks, I have added your proof [here](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/gam-logmean).

Answer (score 23):

The answer by @whuber is quite nice; I will essentially restate his answer in a more general form which connects (in my opinion) better with statistical theory, and which makes clear the power of the overall technique.

Consider a family of distributions $\{F_\theta : \theta \in \Theta\}$ which consitute an *exponential family*, meaning they admit a density 
$$
f_\theta(x) = \exp\left\{s(x)\theta - A(\theta) + h(x)\right\}
$$
with respect to some common dominating measure (usually, Lebesgue or counting measure). Differentiating both sides of
$$
\int f_\theta(x) \ dx = 1
$$
with respect to $\theta$ we arrive at the *score equation* 
$$
\int f'_\theta(x) = 
\int \frac{f'_\theta(x)}{f_\theta(x)} f_\theta(x)
=
\int u_\theta(x) \, f_\theta(x) \ dx = 0 \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
where $u_\theta(x) = \frac d {d\theta} \log f_\theta(x)$ is the *score function* and we have defined $f'_\theta(x) = \frac{d}{d\theta} f_\theta(x)$. In the case of an exponential family, we have 
$$
u_\theta(x) = s(x) - A'(\theta) 
$$
where $A'(\theta) = \frac d {d\theta} A(\theta)$; this is sometimes called the *cumulant function*, as it is evidently very closely related to the cumulant-generating function. It follows now from $(\dagger)$ that $E_\theta[s(X)] = A'(\theta)$.

We now show this helps us compute the require expectation. We can write the gamma density with fixed $\beta$ as an exponential family
$$
f_\theta(x) = \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta x}
= 
\exp\left\{\log(x) \alpha + \alpha \log \beta - \log \Gamma(\alpha) - \beta x \right\}.
$$
This is an exponential family *in $\alpha$ alone* with $s(x) = \log x$ and $A(\alpha) = \log \Gamma(\alpha) - \alpha \log \beta$. It now follows immediately by computing $\frac d {d\alpha} A(\alpha)$ that 
$$
E[\log X] = \psi(\alpha) - \log \beta. 
$$

Comment: +1 Thank you for pointing out this nice generalization.